# No <title> in beta review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

On the [Close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) and [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) pages of the new beta review, the html `<title>` seems to get 'zapped' when ajax has finished dynamically loading the answer/question bodies.

[image]

Comment: I can repro this in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

This is an implementation bug with HTML5 pushstate - when you pass null as a title chrome will leave the title alone however FF will replace the title with the url.